# radio button in radiobuttonlist - uncheck not working - asp.net - using jquery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, radio-button

In developer tools, looks as follwoing for 1st radio button among 2 buttons in radio buttonlist

```
<input name="rbnl" id="rbnl_0" type="radio" value="1">
```

I tried with `$("input:radio").attr("checked", false);` but i am not able to uncheck. Help needed from you guys.. Thanks.

Update:

I checked in the quickwatch...`$("input:radio")[0].checked` is `false`. But in web page it is in **checked**.

Comment: I tried...Same result..not unchecked..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I checked in the quickwatch...`$("input:radio")[0].checked` is `false`. But in web page it is checked ..

Comment: What does the console say when you use `console.log( $('input:radio').length );` ?

Comment: checked in the quickwatch...`$('input:radio').length` giving the answer as `2`..I am having `2 asp list items` in the radiobuttonlist.

Comment: Well, if the result is 2, then `$('input:radio').prop('checked', true)` *should* work.

Comment: Already it is in true(web page)..I want it to be unchecked..When checking in quickwatch it is in false as expected..but in web page it is checked..

Comment: Do you execute the code after the page is loaded? `$(function() { ... rest code goes here ... });`. And do note that only one radio button can be checked (when the have the same name). So `$('input:radio').prop('checked', true)` checks them all, which can't and will probably check the last one.

Comment: Seems to be working: http://jsfiddle.net/fmr7x2xw/

Comment: In document.ready function I called. After web page loaded means where I need to put this or in what function I need to call this...similar to ready func..

Answer (score 0):

You can use the id to access the element directly or using the same selector:

```
$("#rbnl_0").prop("checked",true);//to check it
$("input:radio").prop("checked",true);//to check it

$("#rbnl_0").prop("checked",false);//to unchecked it
$("input:radio").prop("checked",true);//to unchecked it
```

Comment: Please see the comments in the question.